# Prev / Next entry with category param not working

Tags: categories, next-prev, 2.7.3

I have used this a million times before, but for some reason I am unable to get the next and prev entry tags to work with the category param.

Here is the code I am using:

```
{exp:channel:next_entry channel="gallery" category="84"}
    <a id="gallery-prev" href="{path='gallery/view'}/{segment_4}">Prev</a>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}

{exp:channel:prev_entry channel="gallery" category="84"}
    <a id="gallery-next" href="{path='gallery/view'}/{segment_4}">Next</a>
{/exp:channel:prev_entry}
```

As you can see, even if I hard code the category ID it still doesnt work (I normally use it with a segment).

If I remove the 'category' param it works fine.

Any ideas? Bug? I am running EE 2.7.3

Comment: Probably already checked but: are these left inside the channel entries tags, or are the statuses on the entries something other than 'open'?

Comment: @Romans-8---31-39 Hi. The tags are outside the channel entries tag pair, and its using the default status of open. Still can't figure this one out. Its really bugging me.